# Rails join table renders bad sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

UPDATED: to include model relationships

I have a many to many join table between Bands and Events (an event has many bands, a band has many events...)

I have a main page that lists all events, and a recent page which displays events updated in the past 7 days.

Could someone explain why the recent method generates perfect sql with all the joins included

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :include => [:venue, :bands], :conditions => {:updated_at => d1..DateTime.now}, :order => 'events.updated_at desc')
```

And the main method generates horrible sql that queries the band table for each event.

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :include => [:venue, :bands], :order => 'events.day')
```

They both use the same view, there's no other processing/querying going on.  The only difference between the two is the :conditions parameter and the column it's sorting on.  This is driving me crazy!

Sorry, here are my models and their relationships

event.rb

```
has_many :event_bands
has_many :bands, :through => :event_bands
belongs_to :venue
```

band.rb

```
has_many :event_bands
has_many :events, :through => :event_bands
```

event_bands.rb

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :band
```

sql generated by recent:

```
Processing EventlistController#recent (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-03-27 14:58:10) [GET]
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0[0m
  [4;36;1mEvent Columns (16.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `events`[0m
  [4;35;1mVenue Columns (15.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `venues`[0m
  [4;36;1mBand Columns (16.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `bands`[0m
  [4;35;1mEvent Load Including Associations (31.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT `events`.`id` AS t0_r0, `events`.`is_local` AS t0_r1, `events`.`link` AS t0_r2, `events`.`notes` AS t0_r3, `events`.`band_id` AS t0_r4, `events`.`venue_id` AS t0_r5, `events`.`created_at` AS t0_r6, `events`.`updated_at` AS t0_r7, `events`.`day` AS t0_r8, `events`.`band_list` AS t0_r9, `venues`.`id` AS t1_r0, `venues`.`name` AS t1_r1, `venues`.`link` AS t1_r2, `venues`.`map` AS t1_r3, `venues`.`notes` AS t1_r4, `venues`.`created_at` AS t1_r5, `venues`.`updated_at` AS t1_r6, `bands`.`id` AS t2_r0, `bands`.`name` AS t2_r1, `bands`.`link` AS t2_r2, `bands`.`notes` AS t2_r3, `bands`.`is_local` AS t2_r4, `bands`.`created_at` AS t2_r5, `bands`.`updated_at` AS t2_r6 FROM `events` LEFT OUTER JOIN `venues` ON `venues`.id = `events`.venue_id LEFT OUTER JOIN `event_bands` ON (`events`.`id` = `event_bands`.`event_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `bands` ON (`bands`.`id` = `event_bands`.`band_id`) WHERE (`events`.`updated_at` BETWEEN '2009-03-20 14:58:10' AND '2009-03-27 14:58:10')
```

sql generated by main

```
Processing EventlistController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-03-27 14:15:47) [GET]
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0[0m
  [4;36;1mEvent Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM `events` ORDER BY events.day[0m
  [4;35;1mEvent Columns (15.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `events`[0m
  [4;36;1mVenue Columns (16.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `venues`[0m
  [4;35;1mVenue Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT * FROM `venues` WHERE (`venues`.`id` IN (6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5)) [0m
  [4;36;1mEventBand Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT `event_bands`.* FROM `event_bands` WHERE (`event_bands`.event_id IN (1,24,74,2,75,11,12,3,13,129,76,14,77,78,145,4,146,120,15,130,79,147,5,80,148,144,131,81,132,16,28,82,121,133,83,17,134,84,149,6,18,135,85,122,19,7,136,86,20,9,87,25,137,150,22,138,88,151,124,123,139,89,152,140,90,141,91,8,153,21,142,154,125,143,92,126,10,93,94,155,127,95,128,23,96,97,26,98,99,27,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119)) [0m
  [4;35;1mEventBand Columns (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `event_bands`[0m
  [4;36;1mBand Columns (16.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `bands`[0m
  [4;35;1mBand Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT * FROM `bands` WHERE (`bands`.`
```

Comment: What sql does the first one generate if you take out :conditions? That would at least tell you if it's due to the :conditions or to the :order.

Comment: Even better, post the sql generated by both of the examples.  Also, which rails version are you using, 'cause this is an area that's been in flux in recent months.

Comment: It's not the :order, the sql remains the same if I take that out.

I'm using rails 2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they generate two different SQL queries is that Rails, by default, tries to optimize your SQL queries for fewer joins. When you include a list of conditions as part of your find that require the use of other tables then of course the resulting SQL has to include a join. But if all you're asking to do is to pre-populate objects with relationships to the objects you're retrieving then Rails figures it's more efficient to perform several fast queries rather than one big slow query.

Note that this does not cause an N+1 problem, because Rails will try to load all of the associated records in a single query.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  So your recommendation would be to just let  ActiveRecords do its thing?

Comment: Probably, yeah. By all means, write custom SQL if you need to; ActiveRecord can't solve all the world's problems. But in this particular case there is, in fact, a reason for the madness.

Comment: Naturally.  I was just really confused by the results of this simple join.

Thanks!